# CPU Speed below base speed and stuck at 0.79ghz

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, performance, cpu-speed

I have a computer with these specs.

> [image: specs]

One day my old RAM stop working so I replaced it with another RAM which is exactly same.

But after that I realize my games has so much of FPS drops
then I check my BIOS.

Which shows RAM is running at max speed which is supported by my motherboard but my processor speed is 800Mhz.
But my processor is of 2.8Ghz.

So, only thing I tried to fix this was [ThrottleStop](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/) which is temporarily because after restarting system my processor speed again changes to 800Mhz.

Is there any permanent solution to this?

Below are some screenshots of my problem.

**This is Task Manager screenshot.**

> [image: Screenshot.]

**BIOS Main Menu Screenshot that shows processor speed at 800mhz.**

> [image: Screenshot.]

**This is CPU-Z screenshot.**

> [image: Screenshot.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CPU and Memory Running Well Below Set Clock Speed](https://superuser.com/questions/1024497/cpu-and-memory-running-well-below-set-clock-speed)

Comment: [Be](https://superuser.com/questions/1584717/my-processor-speed-drops-to-800-mhz-when-my-lenovo-thinkpad-w541-is-plugged-into) sure your device isn’t running on battery power. [You should also check your power plan.](https://superuser.com/questions/1133533/windows-7-64bit-terrible-performance-cpu-only-running-at-800-mhz)

Comment: Before going further, please check that RAM module. Remove it then start your PC and check speed. Also, DIMM slots may get dust inside and prevent good connection. As a rule, all modules (RAM, PCI cards, etc.) should be inserted, then removed and seated again. This is not some urban myth, I learned it at an official Fujitsu HW training years ago. Worth trying anyway. My guess is that ram module (either dirty or faulty).

Answer (score 0):

For me the the solution was replacing the aftermarket power adapter with an OEM one!
I tried everything else and was about to give up.